# Jboss Wildfly 10 - JMX Remote Monitoring

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jmx, wildfly-10

I am trying to expose a JMX port on my application server for removing monitoring.

In my /opt/JBOSS/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/appserver/configuration/standalone.xml file I have the following:

```
...
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
...

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
    <expose-resolved-model/>
    <expose-expression-model/>
    <remoting-connector/>
</subsystem>

<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:10.0.2.126}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:10.0.2.126}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
</interfaces>
```

In my start script I have put the following JMX details

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I even added in the below as well

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8999
```

However, when I try to startup the app, it never starts and I dont see any logs. Furthermore, I never see the remote port 8999 listening on the server. How do I get the JMX agent to listen on the specified port, such that when you do a 'ss -tuna | grep LISTEN' you get the below

```
tcp  LISTEN     0      50           0.0.0.0:8999                0.0.0.0:*
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the *remoting-connector*, that where the listening port is configured. iirc (this is quite an old version) you need to connect to the management port 9990 or 9999